# Setting up my picture gallery tables

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints, implementation

I am going to create a web application for picture gallery.

So this is how I have created my database tables. (I have excluded the rest of unnecessary tables.)

```
Gallery
Gid    -> Primary key.  
Rid    -> Foreign key from register table.  
Name   -> Name of the image.  
Url    -> Location of image.   
Status -> Enabled or disabled.

Album
Aid    -> Primary key.   
Name   -> Name of the album.

Imagelist  
Iid    -> Primary key.
Aid    -> Foreign key from Album table.  
Gid    -> Foreign key from Gallery table.
```

But for some reason I feel the structure of these tables are wrong. My requirement is user should be able to create different albums from the gallery table.

For example if there are pictures named A, B, C, D. then user should be able to create album named a1 which contains pictures A,B,C; album a2 which contains pictures A, B, D.

I have created this three tables, but I feel that there is something wrong in the table structure. Can someone point me in a right direction?

Comment: I dont see any relation to the user here? How are you linking an album or photo to a user?

Comment: @Rohit I'm using Rid column from Registration table for linking user to other tables like album, gallery etc

Comment: What about the sort, sort type? I see position which is good but sort is like "sort by date", "sort by name" etc and type is like ascending or descending. Also you should add tags In today's world tagging should be a standard feature for photos.

Comment: @Rohit Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't need sorting according to date or other features as I'm not exactly creating a photo album.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not call table with images a gallery as it can mean album to. From my point of view database schema is correct only thing I would change is ImageList table as Iid is not required there, Aid and Gid suppose to be unique index, I would also add field to store image order in album, and also set all tables to InnoDB mode.

Here is example of database schema:

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `gallery_album`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `gallery_album`;
CREATE TABLE `gallery_album` (
  `album_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'name of the album',
  `description` text COMMENT 'description of the album',
  `visible` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'is album visible',
  `position` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`album_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `gallery_image`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `gallery_image`;
CREATE TABLE `gallery_image` (
  `image_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'name of the image used as image ALT attribute',
  `description` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'description of the image used as image TITLE attribute',
  `visible` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`image_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `gallery_relation`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `gallery_relation`;
CREATE TABLE `gallery_relation` (
  `album_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `image_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `position` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`album_id`,`image_id`),
  KEY `image_id` (`image_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `gallery_relation_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`album_id`) REFERENCES `gallery_album` (`album_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `gallery_relation_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`image_id`) REFERENCES `gallery_image` (`image_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: +1 thanks for the suggestion. So I should rename gallery to imagelist and vice versa, right?

Comment: technically its all correct, but for better understanding table name suppose to represent data it stores. If for example you have class named Gallery that represent photo gallery module and some sub classes like Gallery_Image and Gallery_Album it would be wise to call database tables same way.